# How to get a child of child ? Umbraco CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, treeview, umbraco

I am trying to get a collection of all the child pages which sit in a folder under a page. However, I am struggling with this and CurrentPage.Children returns the folder element (as expected).

[image: Example Screenshot]

I am trying to get all the package (whether domestic or international does not matter, just making it better for the content editors to enter content) and display a few fields from the full package document type on the packages page.

What is the best and neat way in which I can achieve this  ?

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: You should try `CurrentPage.Children.SelectMany(c => c.Children)`

Comment: throws an error saying "cannot call lambda expression directly". Can you post an example of how you are recommending using it ? I have tried "var selection = CurrentPage.Children.SelectMany(c => c.Children);" but it does not seems to work

Comment: What if you replace CurrentPage with Model.Content?

Comment: Does not like Children then, and I dont think Model.Content would be dynamic if I were to reuse this code pn another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is get al descedants and filter on the page Level.

```
@{
    foreach (var childchild in CurrentPage.Descendants().Where("Level == " + (CurrentPage.Level+2)))
    {
     <h2>@childchild.Level @childchild.Name</h2>
    }
 }
```

It is also possible to filter on Document Type to ensure you got only the type you want. (the package document type)
Add something like this. `.Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"Package\"")`

Combined:

```
.Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"Package\" && Level == " + (CurrentPage.Level+2))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works as expected. Just one more thing. I would like to make it more strongly typed as you mentioned only for specific document types. How can I add the additional condition to the where clause ? I have tried .Where ("Level == "+ (CurrentPage.Level+2) +"&& DocumentTypeAlias == \"Package\"") Just wanted to know whether this is right ? I will mark your answer correct once this is sorted. Thanks a lot

Comment: With 2 Where's like this: CurrentPage.Descendants().Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"Pagina\"").Where("Level == " + (CurrentPage.Level+2))

Comment: This should also work CurrentPage.Descendants().Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"Package\" && Level == " + (CurrentPage.Level+2)))

Answer (score 1):

I got a way around but not the best, so still looking for good answers. I have used the following:

```
foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Children)
{
    foreach (var package in item.Children())
    {
        <h2>@package.PackageName</h2>

    }

}
```